# Web.Configs across different development environments (and SVN)

Tags: asp.net, svn, web-config

So we have a build process that handles different development web.configs across different environments. We use the ConfigSource attribute and have Team City pick the appropriate file.

That's great, but what do I do when the developers have slightly different environments?

CI, can't help, because everyones getting it straight out of SVN (i.e. CI obviously doesn't build to each developers local machine).

I'll use the ConnectionStrings config section as an example:

```
<connectionStrings configSource=".\Config\ConnectionStrings.config">
</connectionStrings>
```

And we have:
`configs\ConnectionStrings.config (`the generic one)

But I might need to use:

```
configs\ConnectionStrings.dev1.config
configs\ConnectionStrings.dev2.config
configs\ConnectionStrings.dev3.config
```

depending on which developer is using the code at the moment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking into [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx)? They might be able to provide the functionality that you seek while still keeping everything in version control or needing any code changes. Plus it will work for more things than just connection strings, but also directories, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One technique we've used in the past (I recall Ayende mentioning it on a web cast) is that each connection string is named with the developers machine name e.g.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BobsPC" connectionString=""/>
    <add name="JonsPC" connectionString=""/>
</connectionStrings>
```

When in debug we then look for a connection string name of the "current" machine name.

This saves having multiple connection string files. Instead we have one file with multiple connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

We have a separate connection file just like you mentioned with the current machine name in it.
In the build event for the projects that need a connection string we've added a pre built event that deletes the connection.config file from the current project and in the post build event we copy connections.machine.config to connections.config in the current project folder.

In our web.config we have a  so .NET will look in a separate file for the connection string information.

Web.config transformations can only be used when you actually deploy a project. The 'default' web.config will always be used on your local development machine so this is not an option for development environments.

You can extend this mechanism also to app settings and other config files by placing the machine specif ones in the solution folder and just copying them on build.

Comment: Thanks Wouter. I really like this solution. I'll try it tomorrow when I get in to work.